# how to use diffdate function in mysql using variables

Tags: mysql, variables

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `bill`(subid int(10), uprice float, sd date, ed date)
BEGIN
declare numberofdays int;
declare totalprice float;

set numberofdays = datediff(ed,sd);
set totalprice= numberofdays*uprice;

insert into invoice (subscriptionid,price_perunit,numberofdays,totalprice) 
values (subid, uprice,numberofdays,totalprice);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code (syntax) is correct. You might have a problem with variable and field names, try to use different names, e.g. -

```
CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE bill (subid int(10), uprice float, sd date, ed date)
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_numberofdays int;
  DECLARE var_totalprice float;

  SET var_numberofdays = DATEDIFF(ed, sd);
  SET var_totalprice = var_numberofdays * uprice;

  INSERT INTO invoice (subscriptionid, price_perunit, numberofdays, totalprice)
    VALUES (subid, uprice, var_numberofdays, var_totalprice);

  ...
END;
```